# Updating a % of cells in a Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 4 million rows in my table with a blank column called Cancelled Bookings divided into 3 years 2010, 2011 and 2012

```
Booking_Skey BookingNumber ArrivalDate DepartureDate BookingDate CancelledDate BookingValue PitchType_Skey Site_Skey
      124532 B00124532      2010-12-31    2011-01-02  2010-12-31          NULL        10.00              7         2
```

What I need to do is create a code where I can change the % of cancelations for the year I want to update:

So for 2010 I need the following

--Cancelled Bookings--

- 8% of the total bookings are cancelled in the Year 2010, the cancellation date can be equal too or less than the Arrival Date and equal to or greater than the Booking Date
- 20% of the 8% are cancelled on the same day as the Arrival Date
- 20% of the 8% are cancelled the day before the Arrival Date
- 20% of the 8% are cancelled 7 days prior to the Arrival Date
- The rest of the cancellations are randomised between 1 and 90 days

.

```
USE Occupancy
SELECT ArrivalDate, 
DATEADD(day, 
CASE WHEN Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) BETWEEN 0 and 0.92 THEN NULL ELSE
CASE WHEN Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) BETWEEN 0.92 and 0.94 THEN 0 ELSE
CASE WHEN Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) BETWEEN 0.94 and 0.96 THEN -1 ELSE
CASE WHEN Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) BETWEEN 0.96 and 0.98 THEN -7 ELSE
Round(Rand(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * -90,0) END END END END, ArrivalDate) AS DaystoReduce 
FROM Bookings
WHERE DATEPART(Year,ArrivalDate) = '2010' and CancelledDate BETWEEN ArrivalDate AND DepartureDate
```

Can you help?

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: Is this a one-off activity to support testing or similar?

Comment: Hi Chrisb, Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following?  Its not very pretty so will leave that as an exercise for you, but basically its along the lines of calculating the number of each type and then apply the rules against the row number...

```
declare @shareCancelled float, @shareSameDay float, @sharePrevDay float, @shareSevenDays float
select @shareCancelled = 0.08, @shareSameDay = 0.20, @sharePrevDay = 0.20, @shareSevenDays = 0.20

declare @count int, @cancelled int, @sameDay int, @prevDay int, @sevenDays int
select @count = COUNT(*) from Bookings WHERE DATEPART(Year,ArrivalDate) = '2010' and CancelledDate BETWEEN ArrivalDate AND DepartureDate
select @cancelled = @count * @shareCancelled,
       @sameDay = @count * @shareCancelled * @shareSameDay,
       @prevDay = @count * @shareCancelled * @sharePrevDay,
       @sevenDays = @count * @shareCancelled * @shareSevenDays

select ArrivalDate,
DATEADD(day,
CASE WHEN a.RowNum <= @sameDay THEN 0
     WHEN a.RowNum <= @sameDay + @prevDay THEN -1
     WHEN a.RowNum <= @sameDay + @prevDay + @sevenDays THEN -7
     WHEN a.RowNum <= @cancelled THEN -(ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %90) + 1)
     ELSE NULL END
, GETDATE()) as DaystoReduce 
from (
  select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RowNum from Bookings WHERE DATEPART(Year,ArrivalDate) = '2010' and CancelledDate BETWEEN ArrivalDate AND DepartureDate
) as a
```